# How to write a Regex Pattern that ignores period at start

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a C# compatible RegEx pattern that will match IF from the following text

```
IF THIS AND IF() THAT
```

but will not match the IFs in the following

```
DONT.MATCH.THIS.IF OR THIS.IF()
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. I've been playing around with RegExr et al to no avail. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
@"(?<!\.)IF"
```

This will match IF only if there're no dots before.

`(?<!\.)` is a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I had initially been trying to do this the longer way as RegExr doesn't support Negative Lookbehinds but my C# application obviously does. Many thanks.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE you need to define your pattern as verbatim string. Because your regex won't work inside double quotes.